Docker Issue: 'com.docker.dev-envs.exe has Exited'
After the initial successful installation of Docker on Windows 10 Pro, subsequent attempts to launch it result in the error message 'com.docker.dev-envs.exe has exited.' This issue persists consistently despite uninstalling and reinstalling Docker. I have verified that environment variables, Event Viewer logs, and services.msc settings are all correct. Additionally, I have attempted to run the application as an administrator to grant full privileges

did you solve the issue? I am having it right now

Any news about that? I have it also.

Hm, I fixed it with remove all DOCKER_* variables from Environment variables.
I think they were there because of some side effect in previous installations.
